# /dev/null , /dev/random and chrooted bind

Tags: bind, chroot

Hy,

Why a chrooted bind need to mknod dev/null and dev/random ?

Howto say it's necessary but without explain reasons, I administrate chrooted bind servers without theses options, and all seems to work perfectly ...

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many programs and libraries open `/dev/null`, `/dev/zero`, or `/dev/random`.  If whatever you're running in the chrooted jail needs those pseudo-devices, they need to be present inside the jail.  If they are not included, an application may work for a while and then die (when the pseudo device open fails).

You can check your binaries (including dynamic libraries) and see if the devices are mentioned.  From a security standpoint, it's difficult to see any negative implications from `/dev/null` or `/dev/zero`.  If I was being paranoid, or doing covert channel analysis (not that there's that much difference), I'd want to look at the specific implementation of `/dev/random`.